# How to test springjdbcTemplate using junit and mockito

Tags: spring, junit, mockito, spring-jdbc

What is the better approach to test springJdbcTemplate using junit and mockito.
How to mock jdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to mock jdbcTemplate or NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.

Don't mock them. You want to test that data are correctly inserted in and retrieved from the database.
If you mock them, the value of the tests will be weak.

So for your unit tests, just set the datasource to connect to a in-memory database and test the methods you are using.

You can rely on the [3.8.5. Testing data access logic with an embedded databasedocumentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#jdbc-embedded-database-dao-testing) :

Comment: which all libraries or jar to use to test dao layer efficiently.

Comment: spring-test or better if you can use Spring Boot : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test

Comment: Nice, Thanks for the god thought.